# using scrollview to show button behind edittext keyboard

Tags: android, uiscrollview

I have a layout in which I have an image,textview, editbox and a button so whenever the keyboard opens I wanted my screen to scroll down to the button so that the user can always type and press submit button. I did do this by using scrollview but than I removed the scroll view did some changes and now when I again use a scrollview it does not work.
here is the code please check.

layout_file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context="myapp.anis.hotel.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundhotel"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroll">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="Please share your feedback"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/thanks"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/hotellogo"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"

    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/thanks"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:maxLines="50"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/feedback"
    android:hint="Enter FeedBack"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_height="180dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/submitting1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="onSubmit"
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_below="@id/feedback"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and in my main activity I am using the scrollto method to go to my image button.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


ImageButton submit;
EditText feedBack;
static public String saveFeedBack="";
ScrollView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    submit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    feedBack = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.feedback);
    view = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    view.scrollTo(submit.getScrollX(),submit.getScrollY());
    }

public void onSubmit(View view){

    saveFeedBack = feedBack.getText().toString();
    if(saveFeedBack.length() >=4) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter valid Feedback please.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    feedBack.setText("");
    feedBack.setHint("Enter Feedback");
}
```

}

but when I run my application the scrollview scrolls to my edit text but not my button. I have tried adjustResize,adjustPan and all those things but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

ok after much of research I have solved your problem. Actually the thing is when you use scroll to any position inside onCreate it doesn't work because a small delay is required to inflate the view.

So use the below code inside your onCreate:

```
view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
        },200);
```

Hope it Helps!!!

Comment: I tried this but it did not work still the same result. When I click on the edit text and the keyboards shows up the scroll view scrolls to the edit text and the button is behind the keyboard.

Comment: try giving paddingBottom instead of margin and try increasing the padding because I solved my problem the same way

Comment: I am trying to do that but the scroll view just scrolls to the edit text only and does not go below that.